# Why is ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION always 0?

Tags: android, orientation, exif

I want to take a picture and then display it in an imageView.
But the problem is the orientation because sometimes my image is being displayed the wrong way.

All I found here was to get the information of the orientation out of the ExifInterface like this:

```
   ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL); 
    int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    if (rotation != 0f) {
matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);
}
    Bitmap adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

with

```
     private static int exifToDegrees(int exifOrientation) {        
         if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {  return 90;  } 
         else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) { return 180;  } 
         else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {   return 270;  }            
         return 0;    
      }
```

I got this from [[Android get Orientation of a camera Bitmap? And rotate back -90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286714/android-get-orientation-of-a-camera-bitmap-and-rotate-back-90-degrees])

the problem is that I always get an orientation of 0.
And the image is always displayed in landscapeview.
Can anyone help?

Comment: 'if (rotation != 0f) {'. You mean 'if (rotationInDegrees != 0) {'. Which values for int rotation do you get?

Comment: Ive grappled with this issue and so many answers on stack overflow that dont work across all devices. Finally I was able to figure out something that works by sifting through the code of a cropping api.  See my answer here :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971319/image-orientation-android/32747566#32747566